# library for displaying selectable mysql table in java

Tags: java, mysql

Just wondering if there were any libraries out there already written to serv the following purpose:

- Query database.
- Display the results in a list/table that has selectable rows.

Basically allowing a user to select a row in the table/list and the library can tell what is selected?

Comment: @AVD: I believe you are missunderstanding what i am wanting. I am wanting to show the table/list in my application and have it so the user can select rows. What you are suggesting seems to be a client that just gives me a gui for the database it self. I just want to query a database for certain values and show them in a list/table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the [MySql JDBC Connector](http://www.mysql.com/products/connector/) and use `java.sql` API.

EDIT:

Tutorial

1. [Mysql JDBC.](http://www.vogella.de/articles/MySQLJava/article.html)
2. [Basic JDBC Concepts](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-j-usagenotes-basic.html)

Comment: I am new to jdbc and did not realize that it offered some of this functionality in resultset. Thanks.